# Does dart reuse memory for previously used instances?

Tags: dart, memory, memory-management, ram

It is hard to find a good heading for this, but i think my problem comes clear if i post a small code snipped:

```
SomeObject instance = SomeObject(importantParameter);
// -> "instance" is now a reference to the instance somewhere in RAM

instance = SomeObject(anotherImportantParameter);
// -> "instance" is now a reference to a different instance somewhere in RAM
```

My question is now, is the used RAM that was allocated at the first construction reused at the second construction? Or is the RAM of the first instance marked as unused for the garbage collector and the second construction is done with a completely new instance with a different portion of RAM?

If the first is true, what with this:

```
while(true) {
    final SomeObject instance = SomeObject(importantParameter);
}
```

Will then, each time the while is repeated, the RAM be reused?

Comment: In programming languages, where memory are handled by garbage collection, you should, in general, not care about these kind of details which can also change depending on lot of factors. What problem are you trying to solve by looking for this answer?

Comment: I have a loop, parsing a log file. On each iteration, a log token will be parsed, where the structure is almost the same every time. If the construction would always lead to a new memory allocation, i would change to have functions to change the values instead of creating a new instance each time. This would also mean that the definitions of those instances needs to be one scope higher than the loop, making the code a bit less readable.

Comment: Your priority should be readability of code and let the Dart compiler do optimizations. If you can observe a performance problem, then you can look into issues where you can rewrite the performance critical code into something that is less readable but more performant.

Comment: In your specific case, I would assume Dart are allocating a new object for each loop iteration. But the deletion of the old object might happen immediately, after each loop iteration, because of the object being part of a limited scope. If not, it would still just be part of new-generation heap which are constantly being cleaned by other GC releated threads. The whole purpose of new-generation heap is quickly create and later cleanup short-lived objects. So you should not be too worried about having short-lived objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's unspecified. The answer is a resounding "maybe".

The language specification never says what happens to unreachable objects, since it's unobservable to the program. (That's what being unreachable means).

In practice, the native Dart implementation uses a generational garbage collector.
The default behavior would be to allocate a new object in "new-space" and overwrite the reference to the previous object. That makes the previous object unreachable (as long as you haven't store other references to it), and it can therefore be garbage collected. If you really go through objects quickly, that will be cheap, since the unreachable object is completely ignored on the next new-space garbage collection.
Allocating *a lot* of short-lived objects still has an overhead since it causes new-space GC to happen more often, even if the individual objects don't themselves cost anything.

There is also a number of optimization that may change this behavior.
If your object is sufficiently simple and the compiler can see that no reference to it ever escapes, or is used in an `identical` check, or ... any other number of relevant restrictions, then it might "allocation sink" the object. That means it never actually allocates the object, it just stores the contents somewhere, perhaps even on the stack, and it also inlines the methods  so they refer to the data directly instead of going through a `this` pointer.

In that case, your code may actually reuse the memory of the previous object, because the compiler recognizes that it can.

Do not try to predict whether an optimization like this happens. The requirements can change at any time. Just write code that is correct and not unnecessarily complex, then the compiler will do its best to optimize in all the ways that it can.